# My post not going to httppost after login redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller with 2 action result methods. The httpget action takes me to my view with my form to enter in data and then submit to my db. The httppost should be called when I submit and it does if I have the [allowanonymous] attribute but I want the user to have to login to submit so I remove the allowanonymous to be rediredted to the login page. That works but when I login, it redirects me back to the httpget method and NOT to the httppost method. I want it to go the the httppost method, what am I doing wrong?

```
    /// show form to enter in data
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult AddYogaSpace()
    {
        return View();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// to save entered YogaSpace data
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost]
    //[AllowAnonymous] want user to login before submitting to db
    public ActionResult AddYogaSpace(CreateYogaSpaceViewModel createYogaSpaceViewModel)
    {
        // submit code here to repository
        return View();
    }
```

I also tried using

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddYogaSpace", "YogaSpace", FormMethod.Post))
```

in the view but this doesn't work either

Comment: You need to remove the `[AllowAnonymous]` from your GET method so you login before you render the view for `AddYogaSpace`

Comment: Then your form makes no sense. You want to show them the form but then prevent them from submitting it once they have filled it out if they have not logged in.  Terrible user experience. Make both require authorisation.

Comment: Take a look at airbnb. This is how they are allowing hyou to create a new listing. At least they let you define some of the listing before you have to login. I'm trying to follow this as an example.

Answer (score -1):

You **cannot** make the application to remember the data posted to the Login page and post it further after authentication.

The only way to achieve this would be to save all your posted data before redirecting to the Login page and then check if this data is present (after the Login). And if the data is present you should process it and show the appropriate View.